# how to go to "/var/mobile/Applications/some value/Documents" folder iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

i want to check my saved files in the path "/var/mobile/Applications/somevalue/Documents" of my iphone device.

can anyone tell how can i go to that path...

i need to test this path to see whether my file is saved in the path are not, i can't check through iPhone simulator because i am using MPMusicPlayer, so i can't play and save the song using simulator

Comment: Are you trying to get to this directory via code or via osx/finder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
 NSArray *files = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:YOURPATH error:&error];
 if (files == nil) {
     // error...
 }

 for (NSString *file in files) {
    //HANDLE FILE HERE IN YOUR CASE CHECK NAME
 }
```